# Spencer's concept of balance in nature, can it explain consistent 50/50 election results?

Tags: dualism, politics

We are preconditioned to see balance in life.

"If she is beautiful she would have some problems"

"If he is powerful he is probably unhappy."

"If someone is lucky, that means his luck will run out soon."

Could it also mean that 50% of people gravitate to good while the other half have a tendency to support bad (Trmp)?

> **If there is some guiding force (Hegel's absolute idea), crucial elections (Germany 1933, US 2024) with the potential to change human
> history would be the place to prove it.**

Comment: Except elections are often lopsided. Evenly split elections in a 2-party system mostly indicate that the 2 parties learned to do their job properly. When one of them prevails, the other adjusts its positions (or delivery) to appeal to enough of the opponent's electorate to reverse it. The "balance" is a side effect, what each really "seeks" is dominance.

Comment: @Conifold - To have less than 1% split in battleground states, consistently, election after election, it would have to be a 2-party system from Heaven.

Comment: Except most states (and countries) are not "battleground". When you have enough outcomes you do not need Heaven to get some balanced ones.

Comment: Elections are balanced when half the people are unbalanced.

Comment: Balance of nature isn't Spencer's concept - it's at least as old as the ancient Greeks. And it isn't *true*, either.

Comment: @gs I think the Greeks were talking about the balance in personal life, not the balance of forces driving the Universe.

Comment: No, the ancient Greek believed in the balance of forces in nature (elements) and body (juices) where equilibrium was the standard and desired state.

Comment: I used to get angry about elections where it seemed like "just a few" people were deciding "for everyone else". People often focus on the deciding point at the end of a game and ignore the whole rest of the game. So just make games be first point sudden death? Or elections: whoever votes first decides. But then getting to the polling place would be a scene from Hell... Aztec Lacrosse or something. So much for the peaceful transition of power.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance You may be interested in nonlinear dynamics, dynamical systems, and dynamic equilibria, although the math is generally 5 or 6 courses deep in a university math curriculum. If you aren't into math enough to make that an option, David Feldman's *Chaos and Dynamical Systems* (2019) claims to teach many of the important ideas with only algebra. I haven't read it but it might be worth a look.

Comment: @gs - When you get old enough, you start noticing this 'equilibria' in your life, when good things exactly compensate for bad things. At that point, you start to realize that it cannot be explained by fluid dynamics theory.